# How to use filter?

Tags: c++, objective-c, image, opencv, mat

**Note**: I'm coding in C++

I've created a function that is able to extract only the white color of an image.

This function is working very stable!

```
static Mat whitecolorfilter(cv::Mat img, int threshold) {
    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::cvtColor(img, temp, CV_RGB2HSV);
    cv::Scalar  lowerColor(0, 0, 255-threshold),
                higherColor(255, threshold, 255);
    cv::inRange( temp, lowerColor, higherColor, img);
    return img;
}
```

but now I'd like to get a function that is able to apply the same filtering for black color (also with a given threshold).

[image: img]

Is there a way to edit the `whitecolorfilter` function to get the same for the black color? Any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
static Mat blackcolorfilter(cv::Mat img, int threshold)
{
  cv::Mat temp;
  cv::cvtColor(img, temp, CV_RGB2HSV);
  cv::Scalar  lowerColor(0, 0, 0),
              higherColor(255, 255, threshold);
  cv::inRange( temp, lowerColor, higherColor, img);
  return img;
}
```

Choose a threshold around 20 maybe, or lower

it is all about understanding HSV color space.......

If you don't want to detect "very dark red" etc. as black, try limiting the saturation channel higherColor